# Normalizing data in a tailed distribution

Tags: normalization

This is a follow-up from a previous question that I resolved on here earlier.

If a have a data set that is essentially gaussian, I can normalize the data using:

(x - mean)/std

which gives me new set with a mean of 0, and where the value each data point is its deviation from the mean.

Is there an analog to this for a skewed distribution?

I have an inverse gaussian distribution with known (fitted) parameters. How can I transform the data in a way similar to above? Would that even make sense?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you understand *standardization* (which is the correct term here) of a variable to be accomplishing?  In most applications its purpose is to create a variable with zero mean and unit variance--but that will happen no matter what the underlying distribution is (assuming it has finite variance), so obviously this is unrelated to normality.  What, then are the *additional* properties you hope to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my terminology - I'm out of my expertise here. You already helped by explaining that standardization works regardless of the distribution type. I thought it only applied to normal. My thought is that when I look at a data point from a standardized set, it will contain information about how that point relates to the set itself. So, if I pick some point x from the raw set, shown above, say with a value 0.01, I think a number showing its deviation from the mean would be more useful as a predictor.

Comment: I'll try to put it another way to hopefully make my intent clear. I can compute the mean and standard deviation of any arbitrary group of data, then use that information to create a new, standardized set with 0 mean and variance 1. But if I know a priori that the data tend to be tailed (and to a specific type of distribution), is there a more "accurate" way to transform the data. I ask because variance seems to be calculated differently (mean^3/lambda for inv. gauss).

Comment: Variance is variance--its calculation does not vary according to distributional assumptions.  You seem to be confusing *properties* of distributions (such as variance) with *parameters* used to describe those distributions.  Whether standardized values of data are any more useful for prediction must depend on the model, the data, and the objectives of your analysis: that's not something that can be generically answered.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Your comments (and, actually, your questions back to me) helped clarify some things. They also made me realize that I need to take a step back and do some studying.

Comment: This question and the ensuing discussion confuses or conflates normalization meaning standardization and normalization meaning transformation,  Although it may not be a duplicate I can't see that it adds to many existing threads on either topic.

Answer (score -1):

In distributions like this, you need to make assumptions on whether they are log-normal distribution, Pareto, Levy etc. Depending on that you need to apply appropriate normalization. For eg: in my case where I got a log-normal distribution, I applied log to convert it to normal distribution following which I rescaled the values and applied sigmoid to convert it back to the original scale such that it is limited. to 0 and 1. For more details you can look into 30-70 percentile normalization. In your case, it is not a log-normal distribution, so you will need to find some other hack.

Comment: The usual term in my reading is lognormal distribution, not log norm distribution.

Comment: Note that scaling to [0, 1] just requires (value $-$ minimum) / range. ,

Comment: Just scaling the value to [0,1] using min max will not solve this issue. Main problem with heavy tailed distribution is that feature values in the tail region have much higher value compared to the say 70 percent of the data which leads to poor learning/feature representation. You also need to squash the tailed region such that there is a more uniform distribution. This is sort of what histogram equalization does but that is not analytical

Comment: You haven't stated clearly what the "issue" is to you, Otherwise put, normalization can mean anything from (1) transforming a distribution to more nearly normal (Gaussian) to (2) scaling one or more distributions to some common or standard scale, usually $[0,1]$ or (value MINUS level) / scale with (3) it seems yet another idea that values are made closer to a uniform distribution. Your answer appears to jump from one to another and back again.

Comment: Please edit out the non-standard term "log norm". Alternatively, cite a reputable source for that term, which I have never seen before.

Comment: I will edit out the "log norm" part. For our academic discussions we use the term log-norm since it is used quite frequently.

Comment: If it is used quite frequently you can surely give precise example references.

Comment: FWIW I did not downvote, but at the same time I can't see this as a good answer.

Comment: As for the "issue" part, I merely answered what the questioner had asked in the context of normalising heavy-tailed distribution as opposed to the usual gaussian distribution. Merely performing a min-max normalisation for heavy-tailed distribution will not produce any benefit in terms of feature representation of the dataset. That is the whole basis of my answer and nothing else. I am not sure why you are focussing only on the [0,1] part. I provided an answer that makes the distribution uniform and normalises between [0,1]. You need to elaborate more on the jumping part.

Comment: @NickCox, as I said we use the term "log norm" among colleagues and therefore I can't give you a reference but I guess it originated from the python libraries and function names (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html#scipy.stats.lognorm). Also, I am not saying that it is a standard and I do not wish to continue this linguistic debate anymore

Comment: Let's back up. The original question is clear enough in calling (value MINUS mean) / SD "normalization" and the very first comment points out that you can do that calculation for just about any distribution but in statistics that is more often called standardization. The comments on the question don't get as far as the point you are making, which is that a highly skewed distributions are often better transformed, which is a standard point on which I strongly agree (and have often posted on here on CV.)

Comment: A better answer would disentangle different meanings of normalization, standardization etc. as I did in an earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Python documentation which makes your point and mine too. My own favourite software uses command names like `qnorm` and `pnorm` which is just abbreviation. I've never seen anyone call the normal distribution the norm distribution as a result. If I had been in the room when the Python code was named I would have recommended `lognormal` as the name.  The point is, if you like, just linguistic, but standard terms are just that, standard terms.

Comment: If standardisation is the only final goal, then there are steps that we can skip. For eg: you can perform the same steps in log-transformed values and then convert it back by taking just the exponential. I don't see providing an extra step which will also help normalising as jumping topics or otherwise. Ultimately, some experimental steps will be needed to get the best steps. What would also help you is that you look at the history of questions Vincent has asked and this is in relation to some classification task for which I believe, what I suggested is quite useful.

Comment: Also, I agree that a distinction should have been made and I have never disputed that "log normal" is not standard

Comment: We agree, mostly.  I have no interest, however, in looking at the OP's previous questions. Why not improve your answer accordingly? Perhaps the downvoter will then withdraw their downvote. For myself I don't think there is anything in this question that isn't better asked or better answered elsewhere, so I am going to vote to close the question.